# How to redirect response received from an Ajax request to another html page

Tags: javascript, html, json, node.js, mongoose

I have a mongoose database that has data containing a person's first and last name. I have an input field where the user inputs their first name, and then an ajax request that sends the request to the file nameController.js. The code in this file creates a JSON response that contains all the names from the database that include the first name that the user mentioned. I would like to redirect this response to another html page (not index.html) called responsepage.html, and then have the response show up as a list. Does anyone know how to do this?

Here is my index.html code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src gap://ready file://* *; style-src 'self' http://* https://* 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' http://* https://* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/6.1.0/jquery.min.js">
        <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        Enter your first name: <input id="firstName" name="name" type="text">
        <button id="fnamelistbtn" >Click to see names</button>


    </body>

</html>
```

Here is my index.js code

```
window.addEventListener("load", startup);
function startup() {
document.getElementById("fnamelistbtn").addEventListener("click", test);
//document.getElementById("el2").addEventListener("input", myFunc);
}

function test(){
alert("tested");
var firstnameneterd=document.getElementById("firstName");
alert(firstnameneterd.value);
var final_url= 'http://localhost:3000/director/cordovanames?name='+firstnameneterd.value;
$.ajax({
  type:'GET',
  //url:'http://localhost:3000/director/cordovanames?name=Vedant',
  url:final_url,
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(response) {
      var jsonparse=JSON.parse(response);
      alert(jsonparse.length);
      for (i = 0; i < jsonparse.length; i++) {
      alert(jsonparse[i].lastName + ', ' + jsonparse[i].firstName);
      }
  },
  error: function(err) {
    alert("not worked");
    alert(err);
    return err;
  }
});

}
```

Here is my nameController.js code

```
var Name = require('../models/name');
var url = require('url');

exports.cordovanames_list = function(req, res, next) {

  var url_parts = url.parse(req.url, true);
  var query = url_parts.query;
  var fName = query.name;

  Name.find({'firstName': fName})
    .sort([['firstName', 'ascending']])
    .exec(function (err, list_names) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      res.json(JSON.stringify(list_names));
    });

};
```

Here is my responsepage.html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src gap://ready file://* *; style-src 'self' http://* https://* 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' http://* https://* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

        <title>Responses</title>
    </head>
    <body>

      <p id="responsepara"></p>


       <script>
       var responsepara = document.getElementById('responsepara');

       function showresponse(response) {
         var jsonparse = JSON.parse(response)
         alert(jsonparse.length);
         for (i = 0; i < jsonparse.length; i++) {
           responsepara.textContent = jsonparse[i].lastName + ', ' + jsonparse[i].firstName;
         }
       }
       </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried local storage or GET?

Comment: no, how do you do it?

Comment: I just wanna know how to transfer the response from the index.html file to the responsepage.html file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two solutions to the problem that I can think of now. First will be to save the response in [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) and retrieve it on the next page, or pass the response to the next page as a `GET` query string.

**Method 1**

```
// index.js
...
success: function(response) {
  var res = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(response));
  window.localStorage.setItem('response', res);
  window.location = '/response_page.html';
},
...

// response_page.html
...
$(document).ready(function() {
  var response = window.localStorage.getItem('response');
  // Clear storage
  window.localStorage.clear();
  showresponse(response);
});
...
```

**Method 2**

```
// index.js
...
success: function(response) {
  var res = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(response));
  window.location = '/response_page.html?response=' + encodeURIComponent(res);
},
...

// response_page.html
...
$(document).ready(function() {
  var response = window.location.search.split('=')[1];
  showresponse(response);
});
...
```

The caveat with method 2 is that you are limited to a maximum of 2,048 characters.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up doing something similar to Method 1. I saved the response in sessionStorage and retrieved it on the next page and it worked perfectly.